# Using React/Node for responsive email

Tags: node.js, email, reactjs

I am new to Node js and React js. I have been given the following task.

I need to create an email sending system using Node js and React js.
The body of the email should be rich HTML and CSS and should be appear same on different mail servers like Google, Yahoo, Outlook.

So, till now I have been able to generate an express app, that is able to send emails. To get rich HTML and CSS body of the email, I am using an email template from zurb.com/ink. I am able to send a responsive email using Hogan.js .

But I am not sure of where and how to use React js?

Comment: Your React application will use something like Redux to run frontend logic, and this can kick off an AJAX request to the server. Your Node application will be running a RESTful API, which you can use to send an email. Rather than sending an email yourself, you could connect from here to a mail-sending API such as MailChimp or SendGrid.

Comment: Ah, if you are already able to send emails from Express then can you make that into an API?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use React for the process you described. Unless you're designing an Front-end app to send mails.

Comment: Can you provide with some links with the help of which I can get started with the Front-end app to send emails

Comment: try this tutorial, https://medium.com/@rajaraodv/handling-transactional-emails-in-react-redux-apps-8b1134748f76

Comment: I need to construct the email body using React js ..Thats the point of using React

Comment: Can you please have a look at my Github repo. I am actually creating the body of the email using React js so that after it is after rendered by reactjs, it will be an html email sent to whoever the recipient is. https://github.com/DipitMalhotra1/Email-Sending-App#email-sending-app

Comment: Unless you allow the user to create templates on the go, it would be a better idea to use a templating solution for transnational mail considering otherwise you'll need to construct a whole new body every time a mail is sent every single time, which will be very inefficient. And btw your repo does not contain the routes folder so can't go through your code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have updated the Github repo. Till now , I have been able to set the Nodemailer to work for simple text, attachments. I have constructed the Email body(with responsive HTML) in email.jsx. I have put a route('/send') to see how does it actually look on server side.
I am facing problem so as to how can I compile this .jsx template that I have created and send this as html using Nodemailer. I know we can sure do this using Hogan if its a .hjs file. But how can I achieve the same for .jsx file. Please bear with me since I am new to React js